# Find out the parent task of an EKReminder subtask

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I'm using `EventKit` in `SwiftUI` to fetch the reminder items. The problem I encountered is to fetch the parent-child relationship of the reminder items (`EKReminder`). In my Reminders app (in both iOS and macOS), the task has 2 sub-tasks (see the image below), but the `EKReminder` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekreminder) does not seem to have a property to access such parent-child relationship information.

How can I obtain the task relationship using `EventKit`?

[image: reminder tasks examples]

Current codes are (the checking of access granting is omitted):

```
func fetchAllReminders(for store:EKEventStore) {
    let predicate: NSPredicate? = store.predicateForIncompleteReminders(withDueDateStarting: nil, ending: nil, calendars: nil)
    store.fetchReminders(matching: predicate!, completion: { (reminders: [EKReminder]?) -> Void in
        guard let reminders = reminders else {
            assertionFailure("No reminders found")
            return
        }
        if reminders.isEmpty {
            print("No reminders found")
            return
        }
        for reminder in reminders {
            print("Title: \(reminder.title ?? "No title")")
            print("Calendar: \(reminder.calendar.title)")
            if(reminder.hasNotes) {
                print("Notes: \(reminder.notes ?? "No Notes")")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In the Apple Developer Forum, there is a similar post asking the same thing: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655905, no conclusion though.

Comment: how did you create that sub-task "relationship"?

Comment: in the iOS / macOS's Reminder app.